# Converting a UNICODE_STRING to ANSI or vice versa in C

Tags: c, windows, string, unicode

I have a `UNICODE_STRING` that I would like to compare to a null-terminated ANSI string to check if they are the same.  I'm using C.  I would like to avoid including `winternl.h` for `RtlInitUnicodeString`.

What is the preferred method doing this?

Or, alternatively, is there any problem with me using `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert the ANSI string to a wide-character representation and then comparing that to the `UNICODE_STRING.buffer` (with the understanding that the buffer might not be null-terminated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WideCharToMultiByte seems the more logical route.  It can handle strings that aren't zero-terminated and produces a terminated one.  And it tries to do something meaningful with codepoints that don't have a character in the system code page.  Then just strcmp().

Answer (score 1):

I would just convert the ANSI string using `MultiByteToWideChar()`. The `CompareString()` function takes length parameters for each string, so no worries about the missing null-terminator.

Just be careful about which parameters take or return bytes verses characters, and there should be no problems using these functions.